# Rails Gem for a Reservation System

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, rubygems

I've looked around on The Ruby Toolbox and the web and was curious if anyone knows of a GEM for rails to help you build/create a reservation system (or a tutorial)? Something similar to common booking websites like airbnb.com, or expedia.com, etc.

Something that keeps track of the **To** and **From** reservation dates and shows availability, etc. I'm sure you get the idea.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It doesn't strike me as a generic enough system for a gem. It's going to depend a lot on what your specific organization needs.

Answer (score 1):

It would require some extension, but a good starting point could be [Refinery](http://refinerycms.com/), and specifically the [Events Engine](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-calendar) for it.

The Events Engine page lists the addition of a datepicker / calendar in their TODO for 1.2, so you maybe able to contribute to the project.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tutorial building a simple schedule app.
https://web-crunch.com/posts/lets-build-ruby-on-rails-event-scheduling-app-payments

Here is a gem to help manage unavailabilities.
https://github.com/khiet/unavailability

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your Answer is self contained, meaning the answer needs to be here in the Answer itself. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be preferable if you could answer the Question in your own words here and link only as a reference.